# Incorporating "Like Post" feature

Tags: python, django, database, django-models

Hey so I am making a color scheme posting site where people can register and post color schemes they come up with. So far everything is working great, the only thing I have left to do is add a "Like Post" feature. I'm wondering what the best way to implement this would be.

I have two ideas on how this could be done, the first is add an additional field to both the ColorSet (posts) and the User models (for the user model I would set up a new model with a OneToOne relationship to add onto the User model) which would record users that have each single post, and which posts each user has liked to keep track of everything.

So this could look something like this:

```
from django.db import models
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from django.conf import settings

from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
User = get_user_model()

# Create your models here.
class ColorSet(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User,related_name='colorset')
    published_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50,blank=False)
    color_one = models.CharField(max_length=6,blank=False,default='cccccc')
    color_two = models.CharField(max_length=6,blank=False,default='ffffff')
    color_three = models.CharField(max_length=6,blank=False,default='e5e5e5')
    color_four = models.CharField(max_length=6,blank=False,default='f0f0f0')
    color_five = models.CharField(max_length=6,blank=False,default='bababa')
    liked_by = models.IntegerField(blank=True)

    def publish(self):
        self.save()

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('index')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

user model:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

# Create your models here.
class UserStats(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)

    liked_sets = models.IntegerField(blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

In this first option I would have the new model fields (liked_sets and liked_by) be equal to lists containing the ok's of all the Color Sets each user has liked and all the users who have liked each post respectively.

The other way that I'm thinking about would be to just create an entirely new model that tracks the likes for each color set post (not totally sure how this model would look yet exactly).

Aside from which is easier, I wondering which makes more sense from a technical standpoint? Will one of these two options take up more space or create heavier server load?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understand your problem, it can be broken in two parts.

1. Maintaining the total number of likes on a model ColorSet.
2. Keeping the track of all those users who liked a single instance of ColorSet.

Now if I understand your problem correctly(correct me if I'm wrong), when you say:

*new model fields (liked_sets and liked_by) be equal to lists containing the ok's of all the Color Sets each user has liked and all the users who have liked each post respectively.*

you intend to create a field in your database which would simply store a **list of pks** of all the people who've liked a ColorSet model instance. Even if you don't intend to do that, still an `IntegerField` to store such information is(in my humble opinion) somewhat wrong.

Now why you wouldn't want to do that? It's because relational databases are made to recognize the relations between tuples of information and enhance the processing by creating relations. That is why we use relations like `OneToOneField` and `ForeignKey`. They make the processing way faster. If we were to simply store the pk values in a Field, further search them in our database to retrieve information, that would be **something really slow.**

**Now I suppose what you are looking for is [ManyToManyField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/models/#many-to-many-relationships).**

In your problem, you will simply map the ManyToManyField it to the User model.

It would look something like:

```
class ColorSet(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User,related_name='colorset')
    published_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50,blank=False)
    color_one = models.CharField(max_length=6,blank=False,default='cccccc')
    color_two = models.CharField(max_length=6,blank=False,default='ffffff')
    color_three = models.CharField(max_length=6,blank=False,default='e5e5e5')
    color_four = models.CharField(max_length=6,blank=False,default='f0f0f0')
    color_five = models.CharField(max_length=6,blank=False,default='bababa')
    liked_by = models.IntegerField(blank=True)
    #add a simple ManyToManyField which will hold all the users who liked this colorset
    likers = models.ManyToManyField(User , related_name = 'liked_colorsets') 

    def publish(self):
        self.save()

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('index')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

and remove your `UserStats` model to

Now use the following code outline structure to access the information from the database.

1) To get the `ColorSet`s liked by a User:

```
#obtain any user model object; for example: user_object = User.objects.get(...)
user_object.liked_colorsets.all()
#a queryset with all the liked colorsets is returned.
```

2) To get the `User`s who liked a ColorSet:

```
#obtain any colorset model object; for example: colorset_object = ColorSet.objects.get(...)
colorset_object.likers.all()
#a queryset with all the Users who liked this colorset is returned.
```

**One more thing** that I would like to add here. After a User likes a ColorSet, you would obviously want to **add this User to the `likers` field in your ColorSet model**(and increment the liked_by field; I assume you'll manage that). To add a User in the likers field:

```
#obtain any colorset model object; for example: colorset_object = ColorSet.objects.get(...)
#obtain the user model object of the user who liked this colorset in user_object
#and do 
colorset_object.likers.add(user_object)
```

Read more about adding the models in `ManyToManyField` [here in docs.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/relations/#django.db.models.fields.related.RelatedManager.add)

Hope this helps. Thanks.

Comment: Would 1 and 2 go in the views?

Comment: Yes. Both the statements will return a queryset which you can store in a variable. For example: `all_likers = colorset_object.likers.all()`. Now all the likers of the `colorset_object` are in the `all_likers` variable.

Comment: Cool and terms of efficiency is this a good approach or should I be creating a totally new model is handles all the likes?

Comment: As I mentioned, when you're using a relational database, relations are essential and efficient. ManyToMany in django is structured through foreign keys only which makes it highly efficient because fetching and handling tuples(rows of data) from relations(Eg: ForeignKey, ManyToMany, OneToOne) is way more faster than simply searching for some data tuples in a large database. So you should maintain relations(`ManyToManyField` in this case) instead of creating a new database which will increase computation and redundancy.

Comment: Took me longer to complete than I thought but this concept worked, thanks.